# New shape keys distorts model without editing

Tags: shape-keys

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TgwhOzwGO6Wue7M1IwPkBdQmZ3VxEVth/view?usp=drivesdk)I have already created some shape keys for the character, but anytime I add a new one, it deforms the character in a weird way before I even edit it.
I am using blender 2.79b. I have attached the file
. Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: I've edited the question and  added the file

Comment: I can't read your file, sorry, maybe someone will be able, or try another compression format?

Comment: I don't know what exatcly makes this problem, but you can create new shape keys, which works fine, if you adjust all shape value to 0, then click on the little triangle under the minus button, and choose "New Shape From Mix".

Comment: @FFeller your work around works. At least I can keep working until I figure this out. Thanks a lot.